# Python, Word2Vec. Правильно ли я выполняю поставленную задачу?(сравнение фильмов по характеристикам героев)

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

Я только начинаю разбираться в Word2Vec и вроде его смысл стал ясен, но возникают определенные вопросы.
Моя задача это сравнивать фильмы на похожесть путем того что бы находить слова которые характеризуют главных героев( по сути похожие слова). У меня есть корпус из 700 описаний фильмов. То что я делаю:

1. Достаю имена героев и помещаю их в словарь.
2. Токенизирую текст по словам.
3. Убираю стоп-слова и пунктуацию. Перевожу все в ловер.
   После чего использую gensim.Word2Vec , для обучения модели. Вот только возникают вопросы: я в нашу модель отправляю только 1 текст(описание фильма) , и на сколько я понимаю нам и не нужно вкидывать весь корпус ибо это не имеет смысла, ведь главные герои появятся только в одном тексте. То есть я вкидываю в модель 1 текст и потом используя функцию most_similar пытаюсь найти похожие слова к нашему персонажу, например Джон. Вот только результат совсем не очень. Ближайшие слова совсем далеки от смысла.
   То что я думаю, так это то что текст маленький, в словаре модели получается всего 256 уникальных слов, из-за этого нормально модель не обучиться. Но как тогда выполнить данную задачу? Как для такого текста найти слова которые описывали бы нашего персонажа? Может нужно настроить модель Word2Vec( параметры size, window ...) Не могли бы подсказать? Очень запутался.

Comment: Вы подробно описываете, что вы делаете с инженерной точки зрения, но я так и не понял толком, что именно вы хотите сделать концептуально. В чём сама задача - непонятно. Какую гипотезу вы выдвинули и пытаетесь реализовать с помощью модели - непонятно. Сначала чётко сформулируйте: какую задачу вы решаете и какая идея лежит за вашей гипотезой решения задачи. После этого уже можно начинать строить вектора, токенизировать и т.д., но не ранее того.

Comment: А так да, Word2Vec конечно надо строить на большом корпусе текстов, иначе это не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: Хорошо. Попробую объяснить саму идею.
Есть корпус из 700 текстов( описание фильмов)
Нужно при помощи word2vec сравнить 2 текста путем того что бы сравнить описание персонажей этих фильмов. А описание персонажей мы так же должны найти в тексте фильма путем word2vec. 
И потом путем косинусного сходства сравнивать персонажей и на основании этого понять насколько похожи фильмы( типо в одном фильме персонаж убийца в другом персонаж занимается благотворительностью)

Comment: Ок. Чтобы мерить косинусное расстояние между словами (персонажами, чем угодно), вам надо выучить word2vec на всех этих словах. То есть на всём корпусе текстов. Иначе что вы будете сравнивать? Далее. Я так и не понял, как вы собираетесь искать описание персонажей. Будете искать предложения, в которых есть достаточно слов, близких к некоему эталонному набору слов, которыми могут описываться персонажи фильмов? Это моя догадка, из вашего описания я ничего не увидел на эту тему.

Comment: И вот это я не понял: "Достаю имена героев и помещаю их в словарь" Во-первых - как вы их достаёте? Во-вторых - дальше что, вы смотрите все предложения, где есть эти слова и считаете их описанием персонажей? И далее сравниваете эти предложения косинусно между собой? В таком виде я идею понимаю, но она не вяжется у меня со всем остальным.

Comment: Да, я достал имена персонажей и поместил просто в словарь, там все окей, их я пока что не трогаю. А вот по поводу их описания, вот тут как раз проблема. У нас по сути есть текст " Джимми сидел в тюрьме потому что он убил ....."(это пример). И вот мне скорее интересно как можно сделать так что бы я нашел эти слова, близкие к слову Джимми. С тем учетом что текст у меня относительно мал( обычное описание фильма на сайте).

Comment: Я, честно, пока что не знаю как это реализовать. Поставили задачу, что реализуй использую word2vec, и то что тут я писал, это скорее предположения. Но я не знаю как точно это сделать. Что бы в результате было типо Джимми: убил, тюрьма и тд

Comment: Эээ. В том виде, как вы это описали, вам просто надо найти предложения, в которых есть имя Джимми и разбить их на слова. Как делить текст на предложения - я не очень знаю, но должны быть методы. Причём тут word2vec - пока непонятно.

Comment: Если же использовать именно word2vec, то наверное так. Мы считаем, что все описания персонажей чем-то похожи друг на друга. У нас есть некоторый список персонажей, с помощью word2vec обученного на корпусе рецензий мы можем найти слова, близкие к именам известных нам персонажей - это будут имена других персонажей, встречающихся в подобных контекстах.

Comment: Ну а дальше можно искать предложения с этими найденными именами персонажей и смотреть по этим предложениям уже косинусное расстояние между такими предложениями в разных рецензиях

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Попробую так!